# resetTo and immediatelyResetRouteStack action types in react-native-router-flux

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

After successfully login I want to reset my navigator to Home screen with a animation. This is very much possible with [Navigator's resetTo](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#resetto) method but I am using [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux) and this component do not have animation on reset action. Issue is already raised [here](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/1399).

I am looking for `resetTo` and `immediatelyResetRouteStack` functionalities in `react-native-router-flux`, if you have any solution to this let me know please. Thanks.